# Guzzle error on parsing xml with html comment in it

Tags: php, xml, guzzle

I'm getting this error from guzzle. the xml has a html comment in it which I think is breaking it. Any experience with this specifically in relation to guzzle because it is at the point that i try to get the response at xml where this error is through e.g. $res->xml(). $res alone or $res->getBody() don't seem to help me.

> "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be
>   parsed as XML' in
>   /home/mso/public_html/connector/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/Response.php:168
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/mso/public_html/connector/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/Response.php(168):
>   SimpleXMLElement->__construct('Please use a mi...', 2048, false, '',
>   false) #1 /home/mso/public_html/connector/get_dat.php(23):
>   GuzzleHttp\Message\Response->xml() #2 {main} Next exception
>   'GuzzleHttp\Exception\XmlParseException' with message 'Unable to parse
>   response body into XML: String could not be parsed as XML' in
>   /home/mso/public_html/connector/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/Response.php:174
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/mso/public_html/connector/get_data.php(23):
>   GuzzleHttp\Message\Response->xml() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/mso/public_html/connector/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/Response.php
>   on line 17

Comment: possible duplicate of ["String could not be parsed as XML" php error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373507/string-could-not-be-parsed-as-xml-php-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check your xml prior to load using:

```
$oXmlUtilities = new cXmlUtilities();
// Validate xml file by setting internal errors.
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
try
{
    $sTmpString = simplexml_load_string( $sContents );
}
catch( Exception $oException )
{
    $sError = $oException->GetMessage();
}

// If xml validates and isn't empty call guzzle:
if( empty( $sError ) && ( $sTmpString ) )
{
    // XML is valid.
```

Otherwise you may need to parse the string through a regex for html comments:

```
<!--(.*?)-->
```

Comment: turned out that particular xml feed had comments in it that guzzle didn't like. It worked when I switched to using curl (although does guzzle not also use curl)?.